# Creating a custom listview in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, user-controls

I am currently looking for what is best practise when creating a dynamic listview, this will contain a list of clients and once the user clicks this will expand a detailed expander style. I have in the past used user controls, adding a new one each time, however this caused performance issues.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @QuentinRoger He is requested for advice not for coding.....

Comment: Apologise if it's wrong, just want to know what best practise. This will hopefully stop me learning bad habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [page](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/). This seems to be exactly what you want. Instead of a listview, it uses a datagrid.

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful. I will have go with this and let you know how I get on.

Comment: this has worked out really well, however do you know how to access the buttons and comboboxes within a Data Template?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i would like to populate a listview inside and have click events

Comment: Just add a ListView inside the RowDetailsTemplate and set its ItemsSource to your sub items. And bind to SelectionChanged event of that listview. I cannot tell you much more without knowing how your model looks like. Hope you will achieve what you want.

Comment: `<DataTemplate x:Name="datatemplate"><ListView x:Name="lvPipeline" Margin="10,82,10,156" Grid.Column="2" ><\ListView> </DataTemplate>` i cant access the lvPipeline to populate from sql, any ideas?